# Device Orientation and Motion on Webview and Chrome

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing an application that lauches a webview that needs to acces the devices's orientation and motion.
I have a few devices with different Android versions, listed below, and I have different behaviours.

On all devices I can access the devices's orientation on the webview and on Chrome.
The problem is that on some devices I can't access the device's motion on the webview but I can access them on Chrome.
Here's the list:

```
|=======================================================================|
|     Device      | Samsung Galxy   | Vodafone Smart | Samsung Galxy S6 |
|                 |    S4 mini      |    Prime 6     |                  |
|=======================================================================|
| Android Version |       4.4.4     |       5.0.2    |       7.0        |
|=======================================================================|
|                            Device Motion                              |
|-----------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------|
|    Webview      |         X        |                |                 |
|-----------------+------------------+----------------+-----------------|
|    Chrome       |         X        |        X       |         X       |
|=======================================================================|
```

I use to following link to test the device's orientation and motion:
http://code.viget.com/device-motion-demo/

Is there any reason that it works on Android 4.4.4 and it doesn't on Android 5 and greater versions?

Must I add any configuration when I initialize the webview?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that there is a bug on the webview.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=779443

I uninstalled the webview's updates and I get the device's motion events.